# removeAllListeners() doesn't remove listeners at all? (Socket.IO)

Tags: angular, socket.io

I'm using `socket.io-client` in my Angular 8 app.

I'm using a service which looks like this:

```
private socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;
private _alertsObservable: Observable<Alert> = Observable.create();

constructor(channelService : MyChannelService) {
    this.socket = io(environment.socketServer);
  }

refreshAlertsObservable() {
    console.log('This prints once when called')'
    this.socket.removeAllListeners();
    this._alertsObservable = Observable.create(observer => {
      channelService.channelArray.forEach(
        channel => {
          this.socket.on(channel.number.toString(), alert => {
            console.log('This prints multiple times')'
            observer.next(alert);
          });
        }
      )
    });
  }
```

I'm runnig `refreshAlertsObservable()` whenever I detect a change being made to `channelService`.

Whenever I do `this.socket.on()...`, it seems like it adds multiple listeners to the the `channel.number`, which is by design as I understand).
That's why I run `this.socket.removeAllListeners();` beforehand. However, it seems like it doesn't work, because "`This prints multiple times`" keeps being printed in multiples once a message being emitted.
I also tried replacing `on()` with `addEventListener()` and the behavior is the same.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any small github repository to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

RemoveAllListeners expect the array of event names you were listening to. Try maintaining the the listeners created in an array and pass the same to the function. 
Can you please try following way:

```
socket.removeAllListeners([eventName])
```

For more information please refer the [Socket documentation](https://socket.io/docs/)

There are also other similar methods available like off,removeListener etc you can give it a try.

---EDIT---

Or If your socket instance "socket" in the codes is a wrapper that angular returns which may have only on and emit functions please try printing the object and calling it using below method:

```
socket.getSocket().removeAllListeners();
```

Comment: I'm using `socket.io-client`, the signature of removeAllListeners() does not have any parameters

Comment: con you please try to console socket object and check what you are getting in there? If your socket has only emit and on  and getSocket functions then please try the edited post @noamyg

Comment: `Property 'getSocket' does not exist on type 'Socket'`.